# Path of Least Resistance Minimization Problem

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to find a path of least resistance using a matrix c of resistance and a given exogenous vector kOne of the total least resistance from point(n) to point(4) (the destination):

```
c={{inf, 5, 2, inf}, 
   {inf, inf, 1, inf}, 
   {inf, inf, inf, 2}, 
   {inf, inf, inf, 0}}

KOne={4,3,2,0}
```

Using this I want to find the variable kTwo[a] by minimizing the following function:

kTwo[[a]] = min{c[[a,b]]+kOne[[b]]} subject to c[[a,b]] does not equal inf.

The point being that it should create a vector of the path of least resistance from the start to destination.

The *rough* code I've written so far is

```
n = 1;
kTwo = Range[4]; 
(*to create a vector for kTwo that I can overwrite in the while function below*)

While[n < 5,
kTwo[[n]] = Minimize[{c[[n, a]] + KOne[[a]], c[[n, a]] < Infinity}, a]; n++];
```

My big issue is that I get the error "expression a cannot be used as a part specification" and I'm not quite sure how to fix it so I cant really tell what else is wrong with the code. Any help or suggestions with the error or how to tackle the minimization problem would be greatly appreciated as I'm still new to Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand the question, you need not reinvent the wheel - Mathematica has tools to do that.
We start from forming the resistance matrix as (WL uses `Infinity`, not `inf`)

```
c = {{Infinity, 5, 2, Infinity}, {Infinity, Infinity, 1, 
Infinity}, {Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, 2}, {Infinity, Infinity,
 Infinity, 0}};
```

Next, we construct  the  graph `g`corresponding to `c` by

```
g = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[c, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Now we find shortest paths from the vertices of `g` to vertex `4` by

```
spf = FindShortestPath[g, All, 4];
```

and draw these paths

```
Table[HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph@spf[v]], {v, VertexList[g]}]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: [Googling of "exogenous vector"](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=+exogenous+vector+&source=hp&ei=9FMiYqYihd-SBfG4svgD&iflsig=AHkkrS4AAAAAYiJiBACuDkbV51KlhJyTNroXJDLgyLy7&ved=0ahUKEwim7JfshK32AhWFr6QKHXGcDD8Q4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=+exogenous+vector+&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEBYQHjoGCAAQCBAeUABY3yxgk3xoAHAAeACAAdAFiAGEC5IBCzAuMi40LTEuMC4xmAEAoAECoAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) brings nothing.

Comment: Thanks that'd increadibly helpful. By exogenous vector I just meant that kOne is a vector that is already given, in this case it provides the total of the path of least resistance from each node so kOne[[1]] = 4 because the path of least resistance from node 1 to 4 would be 4 while from node 2 to 4 would be  3. Also just to clarify, for the final output is it possible to represent the final least path of resistance from node 1 to 4 as a vector so in this case it would be {3,4} ?